# Remove duplicate based on value

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that will delete the entire row if such conditions are met:

1. ID are duplicate AND
2. In the duplicate ID the cond1 = Hello AND
3. In the duplicate ID the cond2 = 1

See sample table below. The highlighted should be deleted.
The code is slow thus finding a way to optimize it.

[image]

```vb
Sub RemoveDupl()

    'to check if the Incident ID has duplicates
    lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'loop to check all the rows
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Set rangeIDCheck = Range("A:A")
        For j = 2 To lastRow
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rangeIDCheck, Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 6).Value) > 1 And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 15).Value = "Hello" And Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 16).Value = "1" Then
                Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

My second code. I only need how to get the current row number. I searched but got nothing. Enclosed in * is the one I need to be replaced.

```vb
Sub RemoveDupl()
        
    'turning off
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim Counter As Integer

    Set Rng = Range(Range("A1"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        
    For Each cel In Rng
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cel.Value) > 1 And Cells(**Rng.Row**, 15) = "Hello" And Cells(**Rng.Row**, 16) = "1" Then
            cel.EntireRow.Delete
            'cel.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 5296274
        End If
    Next cel

    'turning on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated After Small Correction (Thanks [EEM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4892468/eem))**

For your first code, you can speed it up quite a bit by performing the deletion all at once at the end. Try this....

```
Sub RemoveDupl()
Dim WS As Worksheet: Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")

'to check if the Incident ID has duplicates
lastRow = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row


'loop to check all the rows
Dim aRng As Range

Set aRng = WS.Rows(Rows.Count)

For i = 2 To lastRow
    Set rangeIDCheck = WS.Range("A:A")
        For j = 2 To lastRow
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rangeIDCheck, WS.Cells(j, 6).Value) > 1 And WS.Cells(j, 15).Value = "Hello" And WS.Cells(j, 16).Value = "1" Then
                Rows(j).EntireRow.Delete

                Set aRng = Union(aRng, Rows(j))

            End If
        Next
Next
aRng.ClearContents
aRng.Delete
End Sub
```

For your second code, you can get the row as a property. So your code would be written like this:

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cel.Value) > 1 And Cells(cel.Row, 15) = "Hello"  _ 
And Cells(cel.Row, 16) = "1" Then
```

Hope that works.

Comment: Did you test your answer?

Comment: @EEM I ran a better test and saw a type-o for Row row/s. I fixed. Thanks.